# How to add AWS Timestream datasets to AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, amazon-timestream

I wanna use QuickSight for visualization with AWS Timestream as data source.
But I cannot see any icon of AWS Timestream.

The region of both services are the same(ap-northeast-1).
And when I set up Quicksight, I checked the box to add permission to source AWS Timestream.

I have already checked youtube(https://youtu.be/TzW4HWl-L8s?t=118) and
document(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/Quicksight.html#Quicksight.accessing).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directly asked AWS, then I found the reason. QuickSight does not support Timestream at Asia Pacific (Tokyo) ap-northeast-1 now.